# Doctor of Design (or Other) as PhD Equivalent, Future Risk

Tags: degree, accreditation

From [another question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/97563/are-doctor-of-arts-d-a-degrees-in-math-taken-seriously) regarding Doctorate equivalency, I found the link to this wiki article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_doctoral_degrees_in_the_US

I have a few questions that are interlinked.  I'm sure someone will have a different opinion, but it seems to me these questions are clearer within the context of eachother, which is why I am not making multiple posts.  For one:

> For the purposes of this survey, a research doctorate is defined as "a
>   doctoral degree that (1) requires completion of an original
>   intellectual contribution in the form of a dissertation or an
>   equivalent culminating project (e.g., musical composition) and (2) is
>   not primarily intended as a degree for the practice of a profession."

The quote above is categorizing doctoral degrees by their intention.  However, it is not clear how this intention is defined.  One school may consider a doctorate as a specialized version of a PhD, while another refers to it for industry.  Case in point, from the [Doctor of Design at Harvard](https://www.gsd.harvard.edu/doctoral-programs/doctor-of-design/):

> Thesis topics investigate more specific issues within individual or
>   combined research areas, and do not necessarily correspond to
>   individual academic disciplines. Instead, they are often
>   interdisciplinary in nature, involving faculty and resources from
>   other graduate schools at Harvard and contribute to expanding the
>   intellectual range of design research.

This states there is a thesis, research, and contribution to the field.

On the other hand, [NCSU states their Doctorate of design](https://design.ncsu.edu/academics/doctor-of-design/#overview) as:

> Established in 2016-17, the professional Doctor of Design (DDes)
>   program is an advanced degree program for established design
>   practitioners, which complements the existing PhD in Design.

Which seems to fall under the category defined as (2) in the wiki quote "is not primarily intended as a degree for the practice of a profession".  Maybe I am reading into it wrong, but it does seem to suggest there are differences in how a school interprets the role of one program over another.

**1) So is the equivalency based on what type of program you went through, or based on an assessment of the supposed meaning, averaged over schools?**

Second, based on either the assessment, or university specific approach to the degree purpose, it seems the NSF keeps changing equivalency. From the wiki article:

> part of an ongoing program of assessment that saw the number of
>   recognized research degrees reduced from the 52 recognized from 1994
>   (the earliest report archived online) to 1998, falling to 48 from 1999
>   to 2003 and to 24 in 2004.The number rose to 20
>   in 2007, with the Doctor of Design and Doctor of Fine Arts being
>   re-recognized after being removed from the 2006 list, before falling
>   again to 18 in 2008 when the Doctor of Music and Doctor of Industrial
>   Technology were dropped.

**2) If the acceptance keeps changing, such as the case in Doctor of Design, is the year received connected to the recognition of it as a research degree?**

And finally, 
**3) is it then risky to get a degree that does not specifically say Doctor of Philosophy, as one day NSF may decide it doesn't accept it anymore?**  If there are any examples within the community that this has happened to, or schools/tenure committees that have run into this issue, those answers would help.