# Industry value of Doctoral degree when compared To a PhD in Computer Science

Tags: phd, industry

I'm planning to do a Doctoral program in computer science. However, there are Two degrees:

1. Doctor of computer science (DCS Doctoral degree)
2. Doctor of philosophy in (PhD) computer science

I am a working professional and I'm planning to do one of these degrees mainly for career advancement. I'll be continuing in industries and not interested in the teaching profession. It is common to see industries specifying PhD as a mandatory requirement for some jobs; however, I have not seen the same thing for DCS degree.

Therefore, I would like to know which one of them is widely accepted by industries?

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: I cannot understand how this question is considered to be a shopping question by one user.

Comment: I cannot understand how another user considers the question to _strongly depend[] on individual factors_. Perhaps I'm reading the question differently: Which degree is ranked higher, (1) or (2)? Which gives way to: Can a candidate with (1) apply for a job that requires (2)? If that's the correct reading, then perhaps the OP can edit to make the question clearer.

Comment: Are these terms specific to some country?

Comment: For _Doctor of Computer Science_, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_of_Computer_Science

Comment: I think _PhD Doctor of philosophy in computer science_ should be read as either (1) _PhD in computer science_ or (2) _Doctor of philosophy in computer science_. I don't know what _PhD Doctor of philosophy_ means.

Comment: Related question: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/120801/4484

Comment: AFAIK both of these are doctoral degrees. Unless this is another example of computer science being A Bit Different, they may differ only in name and awarding institution.

Comment: @user2768 I didn't flag to close, but the I could possibly see this being an _individual factor_ question because the OP asks within the context of himself (e.g., _I am doing_...) rather than a broader context (e.g., _What is the difference of a PhD and DCSD from an industry perspective?_).

Comment: You might get a better answer (from the industry perspective) at workplace.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 4):

> [[a] DCS is not considered equivalent to a Ph.D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_of_Computer_Science)

So, a job posting seeking a candidate with a PhD in computer science is only seeking (2), candidates with only (1) should not apply.

> will the company treat both the doctoral programs equally or does one have edge over the other?

PhD has the edge over DCS.

Comment: As far as I can tell, industry typically values applied knowledge more. Do you have any references for your last sentence?

Comment: @Roland It is considered a higher degree. In the context of the question, in a job ad that requires a PhD, a candidate with just a DCS has a disadvantage, since the ad demands a higher degree. Whether _industry typically values applied knowledge more_ is beyond the question's scope.

Comment: Yes, I agree that the phd is considered a higher degree. But it doesn't follow that it has the edge in an industry career. It only has the edge for these specific job postings. But op seems to ask a more general question.

Comment: @Roland That's not my reading of the question.

Comment: They are "planning to do a Doctoral program", they are not planning to apply to a specific job. They are basically asking for career advice. I'm tending towards adding another close vote (because how a company treats these degrees depends on the individual company or even the individual job).

Comment: @Roland But the question is about jobs: _it is common to see many industries posting jobs for PhD in computer science. Do they mean only 2 or 1 also can apply. In short, will the company [that posted such a job ad] treat both the doctoral programs equally or does one have edge over the other?_

Comment: Well, let's agree to disagree.

Comment: Ultimately, the question is poorly written, which is why I have asked for clarification (https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/134971/industry-value-of-doctoral-degree-when-compared-to-a-phd-in-computer-science/134977?noredirect=1#comment359588_134971). Unfortunately, down voting now won't give the OP sufficient time to clarify. Stackexchange should add a feature for that, e.g., _on hold until edited_.

Comment: I'm not a fan of answers to poorly written questions, especially if the question can be interpreted in different ways.

Comment: @Roland The number of poorly written questions is huge, unfortunately.

Comment: user2768 and @Roland I have rephrased the question based on the comments. Thanks much for all the replies!  hope the question is much clear now. Thanks!

Comment: @RajKumar *It is common to see industries specifying PhD as a mandatory requirement for some jobs; however, I have not seen the same thing for DCS degree. Therefore, I would like to know which one of them is widely accepted by industries?* Surely the answer follows immediately: A PhD is more widely accepted. But, as Roland has hinted, you're perhaps asking the wrong question.

Comment: +1. I would add that a PhD diploma is recognized internationally (despite differences by country), whereas a DCS is unknown in many countries.

Comment: Whether a PhD is a "higher" degree than a DCS or not is irrelevant.  Whether industry "typically values applied knowledge more" is irrelevant.  The difference between PhD and DCS is that a PhD is a _research_ degree, while a DCS is not.  **If an employer is advertising for someone with a PhD in computer science, they want someone with documented _research_ experience.**

Comment: According to the cited wikipedia page, a _DCS...is an **applied research doctorate** in computer science awarded on the basis of advanced study and **research**_.

Answer (score 1):

Let me give some perspective. At one time (prior to 2003), the NSF (in the US) considered a wide variety of doctorates to be [*Research Doctorates*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_doctoral_degrees_in_the_US) and therefore equivalent to the PhD. That changed in 2003 and many of those are no longer considered at the same level.

Moreover, for purposes of obtaining NSF grant funding, they are equivalent to the Masters degree. This is a big deal for an academic.

However in industry, each company will make its own rules for people who want to do industrial research. I know of at least one company where this would be a problem for someone holding a not-PhD doctorate. But for others it wouldn't matter.

Part of the subtlety here is that most of those other doctorates are "applied" doctorates rather than "theoretical" ones. For many companies, good application knowledge is actually preferred.

I'd advise you to look around a bit at companies you might want to work for, and even your current employer, for guidance. And for maximum flexibility, get a degree, like a PhD, that is considered to be a *Research Doctorate*. Follow the link above for more information.